# Reference an image from absolute path at runtime typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native, electron

So I am writing an electron app with react and typescript and I am trying to set the CSS background property of a div to a custom image specified by the user. I have this code inside my react component:

```
getBackgroundImageStyle() {
    let backgroundImage = getBackgroundImageFile();
    return {
         backgroundImage: 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')',
         backgroundPosition: 'center center',
         backgroundSize: 'cover',
    }

}
```

where background image is an absolute path to a file the user specified, but I always get the error that the resource could not be found.
I have tried doing `backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(backgroundImage) + ')'`, wierdly that only works if I specify the file in plaintext and if I use a relative path, like `require("../../../../image.png")` works where `require(backgroundImage)` does not work even if `backgroundImage` is a string set exactly to `../../../../image.png`

What is the best typescript way to do this?
Something that might also be of note, is I'm using yarn for package management

Thanks

Comment: How are you accepting images from the user? As a JS `Blob` object or similar? Can't you use `URL.createObjectURL()` and use that?